# Create the array of spreadsheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following array of worksheets:

```
 Dim ArrayOne(11) As Worksheet
ArrayOne(0) = "January 2015"
ArrayOne(1) = "February 2015"
ArrayOne(2) = "March 2015"
ArrayOne(3) = "April 2015"
ArrayOne(4) = "May 2015"
ArrayOne(5) = "June 2015"
ArrayOne(6) = "July 2015"
ArrayOne(7) = "August 2015"
ArrayOne(8) = "September 2015"
ArrayOne(9) = "October 2015"
ArrayOne(10) = "November 2015"
ArrayOne(11) = "December 2015"
```

and when I'm trying to do the following:

```
Set ArrayOne(1) = Sheets.Add
Sheets.Add.Name = ArrayOne(1)  
ArrayOne(1).Protect DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=False, _
```

It gives me an error:

> Object variable or With block variable not set

And the error points here:

```
 ArrayTwo(0) = "January 2015"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to assign a `String` value to a `Worksheet` data type.  You could declare `String` variables for the worksheet names, and `Worksheet` variables for the actual worksheets.  Something like this perhaps:

```
Dim strArrayOne(11) As String
Dim wsArrayOne(11) As Worksheet

strArrayOne(0) = "January 2015"
strArrayOne(1) = "February 2015"
strArrayOne(2) = "March 2015"
strArrayOne(3) = "April 2015"

Set wsArrayOne(1) = Sheets.Add
Sheets.Add.Name = strArrayOne(1)
```

Comment: Just a quick question, do i  even need this -> strArrayone(1).Protect DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=False, _

Comment: If you are just adding an unprotected worksheet and naming it, then I don't see any reason for that line of code.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `ArrayOne` as type `Worksheet`, but you're populating it with strings.

Should be like this:

```
Dim ArrayOne(11) As Worksheet
Set ArrayOne(0) = Worksheets("January 2015")
Set ArrayOne(1) = Worksheets("February 2015")
'...etc
```

You don't show where `ArrayTwo` comes from.